# Where is the Windows 7 "LocalService" account's home directory?

Tags: windows-7, local-system

Windows 7 allows you to configure services to use the [LocalService user account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), rather than the default [LocalSystem user account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If the services run as LocalSystem, and try to create a file in the user's home directory, then it gets created here: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile

However, when it is run as LocalService, I cannot find where the home directory is, if it has one at all.

Comment: Why has this question been closed? It demonstrates a minimal understanding of the problem and it is relevant to professional system administration, so both close reasons listed do not apply.

Answer (score 13):

Ok, I've found it here:

**C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService**

along with one for NetworkService